# Find object in array, to return the objects data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I have entries into the mongo database that hold daily entries and im trying to find a specific entry within an array. For example trying to find the coca cola for this user on the date using mongoose.

```
"_id": ObjectId("ID"),
"user_id": ObjectId("ID"),
"date": today,
"snacks": 
[
  {
    "nutrients": [{...}],
    "servings": 1,
    "name": "Coca-Cola"
  }
]

user_food.find({user_id : req.session.user_id, date: today}, {snacks:{[name:{"Coca-Cola"}]}}
```

I can query and retrieve the full entry by date with the following query:

```
user_food.findOne({user_id : req.session.user_id, date: today}, function (err, diary) {...});
```

My only problem is obtaining only the specific entry object by the name: snack - name.

Comment: You could filter through the snacks array which  will return you the array pertaining to just the name (Coca cola in this case) ```obj. snacks.filter((snackItem) => snackItem.name === 'Coca-Cola')```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your query to look like this:

```
user_food.find({user_id : req.session.user_id, date: today, 'snacks.name': 'Coca-Cola' })
```

This will only find documents that have a snack name of "Coca-Cola" you can then project it if you wish to only send back relevant information

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't being clear, I just want to get `{
    "nutrients": [{...}],
    "servings": 1,
    "name": "Coca-Cola"
  }` returned from the query.